# PhantomJS Can't submit form?

Tags: javascript, java, html, forms, phantomjs

Can someone please take a look at this form

http://www.zoopla.co.uk/friend/42816744?section=for-sale&search_identifier=6323219902a84fc51cd97861178ef6ce

Using chromedriver is fine but PhantomJS won't click the submit button, well maybe it does click it but the form isn't being sent.

- JavaScript executor - nothing
- Using the button id - nothing
- Using the button xpath - nothing
- Waiting 1 minute before clicking the button - nothing
- Waiting 1 minute after clicking the button - nothing
- Used 5 different version of PhantomJS - nothing
- Set different user agents - nothing
- Set different SSL allowances - nothing
- Used .click() - nothing
- Used .submit() - nothing
- Used .submit() on other form elements - nothing
- Set different window sizes - nothing
- Assert the element is displayed returns true
- No errors in the log

None of these options works. When I take a screenshot I can see the fields have been populated with the data but the form just isn't being submitted, I'm not taken to the thank you page.

I can go to the page, enter NO data and submit the form and I will see the client side error message display telling me the field is required.

What could possibly be causing this?

Update adding a section of code, note that this does work in Chrome so it can't be a coding error:

```
public void fillInForm(){
//Enters all the details
}


// Tried all three of these findBy, I do initalise the elements in the page construtor PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
    //@FindBy(id="friend_submit")
    //@FindBy(xpath="//input[@type='submit']")
    @FindBy(xpath="//div//input[@type='submit']")
    private WebElement submitEmailButton;

    public void submitForm(){

        Assert.assertTrue(submitEmailButton.isDisplayed());

        webclientTestHelpers.scrollToElement(submitEmailButton, driver);

        // Trying to click using Java script
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
        js.executeScript("document.getElementById('friend_submit').click();");
        System.out.println("WE ARE ON::" + driver.getCurrentUrl()); // Page not moved

        System.out.println(submitEmailButton.isDisplayed() + "" + submitEmailButton.isEnabled()); // returns true ture so obviously the button click didn't work

        submitEmailButton.click();

        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        // Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\screenshot\\TOOKASHOT.png")); // THis screenshot displays all the form details are correctly set so clicking the button should have sent the form
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please add the minimal reproducible code example of what you have tried.

Comment: @Vaviloff I've added some code above.

Comment: What version is PhantomJS binary?

Comment: Here's a script to submit that form in raw *PhantomJSese*: http://pastebin.com/GVBiLjCt . [Works fine](http://i.imgur.com/Hahipdj.png) on PhantomJS v2.5b, only requires reCaptcha to really send. Could be smth specific in Java driver. Note: native `click()` won't work under v2.

Comment: @Vaviloff thanks for the reply. Its strange I don't see the reCaptcha, I've tried on multiple devices https://uploadpie.com/EL4zgA I'm willing to bet even if you could click the captcha it wouldn't go through, I can fill in the form fine I have screenshots to prove it but clicking the button does nothing with data in the fields. If I click the button with no data I get the "This field is required." error next to the email field. It's just strange that I can click the button and see errors when expected, but with valid data I get stuck on the page.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you further as I don't speak Java. Is it possible to subscribe to PhantomJS `page.onError` callback somehow? I'm sure something weird happens onSubmit. And once more, what is your PhantomJS version? Is it [the latest](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads)?